# Registration and Custom Post Types - How to synchronize information?

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, user-registration, permissions, publish

I am building a platform where service providers can offer their services to potential customers. Therefore, I have two user roles, one "customer" who can only create an account and read; and "providers" who can create an account, and publish a post with their account information.

Here is the problem I am having:
I created a Custom Post Type for "Providers", and they can choose their role upon registration, but I can't seem to figure out how to connect the registration form (via Profile Builder Plugin) to their particular post type. Meaning: their Custom Post Type entry should be created displaying the information they provided in their registration form.

Is this possible? If so, can somebody point me in the right direction, please.

Comment: Not sure what the plugin does after an account is created or if it provides a hook, but essentially you'd need to trigger a post creation of your CPT with the data the user provided.  I have done this with WooCommerce, but WooCommerce provides hooks.  Your best bet would be to ask the plugin author.

Comment: You can use this plugin to sync users to a post type: [https://facetwp.com/help-center/add-on-features-and-extras/user-post-type](https://facetwp.com/help-center/add-on-features-and-extras/user-post-type), although it is quite expensive.
Other than that, all you can do is allow users to post their profile as a parent custom post type and figure out a way of restricting that post to one while allowing multiple posts of child post types.
It is doable, I have done it! The trick is to make their user fields (populated from the user details) non-editable, which you have to do with Jet Engine.